# Using a return/stop function on click

Tags: javascript, return, exit

Currently closee to finishing a slideshow using html and JavaScript. My last problem is creating stop button which needs to use a return function (I assume) Or some sort of exit function. It is an image slideshow that runs automatically, can be paused, skip image, go back an image and so on. I'd like the stop button to kill the autoRun function and set the image back to the first default image. I've set up a function which I'm guessing is totally wrong as it is not working.

The HTML

```
  <td class="controls">

  <button onClick="autoRun()">Start</button>
  <button onClick="changeImage(-1); return false;">Previous Image</button>
  <button onClick="pause();">pause</button>
  <button onClick="changeImage(1); return false;">Next Image</button>
  <button onClick="Exit();">Exit</button>



  </td>

</tr>
```

All buttons are working besides the last one

JavaScript

```
var images = ["HGal0.jpg", "HGal1.jpg", "HGal2.jpg", "HGal3.jpg", "HGal4.jpg", "HGal5.jpg", "HGal6.jpg", "HGal7.jpg", "HGal8.jpg", "HGal9.jpg", "HGal10.jpg", "HGal11.jpg", "HGal12.jpg", "HGal13.jpg", "HGal14.jpg", "HGal15.jpg"];
var interval = setInterval("changeImage(1)", 2000);
var imageNumber = 0;
var imageLength = images.length - 1;

function changeImage(x) {
imageNumber += x;
// if array has reached end, starts over
if (imageNumber > imageLength) {
    imageNumber = 0;
}
if (imageNumber < 0) {
    imageNumber = imageLength;
}

document.getElementById("slideshow").src = images[imageNumber];

return false;
}

function autoRun() {
interval = setInterval("changeImage(1)", 2000);

}

function pause(){
clearInterval(interval);
interval = null;
}

function Exit(){
return;
}
```

I'm not fully understanding the return statement in the Exit function, as most examples I've looked at run the function when an 'if' statement is met, whereas I'd like mine to execute when the Stop button is clicked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `return` statement simply exits the function in which it appears, it doesn't cause other things to stop. So this:

```
function Exit(){
return;
}
```

...has the same effect as this:

```
function Exit() { }
```

That is, the function doesn't do anything at all.

> *I'd like the stop button to kill the autoRun function and set the image back to the first default image.*

OK, so have your `Exit()` function call your other functions:

```
function Exit() {
  pause();            // this will stop the slideshow
  imageNumber = 0;    // reset to the first image
  changeImage(0);     // change to that image
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see now, much better. Understandable too, thanks very much for this